# Cannot start container lstat no such file or directory

Tags: docker, boot2docker

Windows 8.1 using boot2docker

I created a container for gitlab using https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab

It works but now I can't start the container because of a missing directory whereas the directory exists on my host (Windows).

The command to run the container the first time:

`docker run --name='gitlab' -it --rm -e 'GITLAB_BACKUPS=daily' -e 'GITLAB_PORT=10080' -e 'GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022' -p 10022:22 -p 10080:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/bin/docker -v /k/home/gitlab:/home/git/data sameersbn/gitlab:7.7.2`

The command to start the container:

`docker@boot2docker:~$ docker start gitlab
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container gitlab: lstat /k: no such file or directory
FATA[0000] Error: failed to start one or more containers`

The issue comes from `-v /k/home/gitlab:/home/git/data`

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
d6d93182dd57        sameersbn/gitlab:7.7.2        "/app/init app:start   47 hours ago        Exited (128) 45 hours ago                       gitlab
67c89e0dd5a7        sameersbn/redis:latest        "/start"               2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago      6379/tcp            redis-gitlab
02f0c98b2827        sameersbn/postgresql:latest   "/start"               2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago      5432/tcp            postgresql-gitlab
```

The logs:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker logs gitlab
Database connection details not specified.
Will try to spin up a new postgresql image with the name postgresql-gitlab.
Please manually configure the database connection in production.
Using existing postgresql container...
Redis connection details not specified.
Will try to spin up a new redis image with the name redis-gitlab.
Please manually configure the redis connection in production.
Using existing redis container...
Waiting for database server to accept connections
Starting supervisord...
2015-02-13 18:54:06,336 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2015-02-13 18:54:06,336 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sidekiq.conf" during parsing
2015-02-13 18:54:06,336 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/cron.conf" during parsing
2015-02-13 18:54:06,337 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx.conf" during parsing
2015-02-13 18:54:06,337 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/sshd.conf" during parsing
2015-02-13 18:54:06,337 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/unicorn.conf" during parsing
2015-02-13 18:54:06,348 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2015-02-13 18:54:06,348 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2015-02-13 18:54:06,349 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2015-02-13 18:54:07,351 INFO spawned: 'sidekiq' with pid 308
2015-02-13 18:54:07,352 INFO spawned: 'unicorn' with pid 309
2015-02-13 18:54:07,353 INFO spawned: 'cron' with pid 310
2015-02-13 18:54:07,354 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 311
2015-02-13 18:54:07,354 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 312
2015-02-13 18:54:08,805 INFO success: sidekiq entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-02-13 18:54:08,805 INFO success: unicorn entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-02-13 18:54:08,805 INFO success: cron entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-02-13 18:54:08,805 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-02-13 18:54:08,805 INFO success: sshd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2015-02-13 21:27:09,199 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2015-02-13 21:27:09,199 INFO waiting for cron, nginx, sshd, sidekiq, unicorn to die
2015-02-13 21:27:09,200 INFO stopped: sshd (exit status 0)
2015-02-13 21:27:09,202 INFO stopped: nginx (exit status 0)
2015-02-13 21:27:09,202 INFO stopped: cron (terminated by SIGTERM)
2015-02-13 21:27:09,391 INFO stopped: unicorn (exit status 0)
2015-02-13 21:27:11,219 INFO stopped: sidekiq (exit status 0)
```

I am a very beginner in Docker.

Comment: is /k a windows share over cifs/samba?

Comment: no it's a regular directory

Comment: what are the permissions on /k?  `ls -lad /k`